# Jackson, how to set up so could be used?

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to use Jackson for easily convert between json and java objects.
So I imported three jars into my project Jackson-annotations,jackson-databind, and Jackson-core. But still when I write ObjectMapper in the class, it doesn't recognized it.

Person ob = new ObjectMapper().readValue(content, Person.class); Here ObjectMapper is always underlined with red. I tried to manually import something still nothing.

Comment: Pls specify the versions of these jackson libraries as well.

Comment: Please read & act on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the class `ObjectMapper` is in jackson-databind.

Do you have `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` in your imports?

How are you setting up your class path? Are you using Maven? Is this in your IDE?

Comment: No Maven, I just add the jars in netbeans to the Libraries.

Comment: Where are you getting the libraries from? Are you following the instructions for adding libraries to NetBeans as demonstrated here: https://netbeans.org/kb/74/java/project-setup.html#projects-classpath

Answer (score 0):

ObjectMapper class present here

org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper

Please try to import jar which available here...
http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jackson-all/jackson-all-1.9.0.jar.zip

Comment: This is the old version of Jackson. Jackson is now in the org.fasterxml package. Also, it would be better to download Jackson from their website http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload